# PHP: How do you adjust for date_default_timezone_set when it occurs after date/time variables have already been defined?

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out how to adjust the way mktime values are interpreted  when the timezone is set after a variable has already been defined.

```
<?php
function drawCalendar($month, $year) {
  $startDate = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year);
  //some other code
  //echoing date('Y-m-d', $startDate) here returns the expected value.
  //then I include my db connection file which     
  //includes the following:
  if (!isset($_SESSION['timezone'])) {
    date_default_timezone_set("America/Denver");
  } else {
    date_default_timezone_set($_SESSION['timezone']);
  }
  //echoing date('Y-m-d', $startDate) immediately after this
  //reveals a new timezone-adjusted date.
  //Including the db connection before setting the $startDate variable 
  //addresses it. But I'd prefer
  //to keep the connection down with the sql query in my code
  //...
}?>
```

Comment: The `mktime` function returns an `int`-type value which doesn't contain any information regarding the timezone (and if you print it you will get a number and not a date-string), so the question is how exactly you `echo`  the `$startDate` in your example?

Comment: I'm appending the value to a hidden div I use for debugging like this: 
$calendar .= "<div class='debug'>Before db connection: " . date('Y-m-d', $startDate) . "</div>";
Then I have a second one after the db include. I verified the date function itself wasn't altering it.

Comment: So you are using `date`, and not the `startDate` value. Update the qestion with that information.

Comment: Aha. And now it makes sense. The date and timezone functions aren't changing it, they're just interpreting the int value in the variable differently based on the offset. Moving my db include to the top (as opposed to further down where my query's actually going to happen) seems to address the issue. Not sure if there's a better way to do that.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the question here now...